# Reorganize data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a list of (let's say) phone numbers and people. Each person has a varied quantity of phone numbers. I have the data arranged with phone numbers in column A and the owners in column B.

[image: before]

I want to restructure the data like this:

[image: after]

The list is alphabetically sorted by column B, so I could actually just copy+paste the phone numbers. However, what I am actually working with is a list of 4000 values divided between 80 owners, and I am doing this list once a week so I would like to do this a bit smarter.

I found this formula from another question, which I've adapted to my spreadsheet ("export" is a tab in my sheet):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(export!A$2:A$4799,SMALL(IF(export!B$2:B$4799=C$1,ROW(export!A$2:A$4799)-ROW(export!A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")
```

However, it is not working.

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you need to copy paste the numbers to separate worksheet per person? What is "owner", is it in a new column, or just in column B??

Comment: Also, it would help to post an example of the data structure.  Is it one phone number and one name per row vs. all phone numbers per person in a single cell?  Does the formula reflect your spreadsheet or is that what you found somewhere else?  What are you trying to do with the data, just copy it to somewhere else?  What are the criteria mentioned in the title?  In what way isn't the formula working (and what do you expect it to do)?

Comment: Thank you both of you. I did not know how to add a table to my post, that is why there is no examplary data. I have tried now.

I have data in this format:
![Data input](http://imgur.com/SQtbJD5)

And I want it in this format:
![Data output](http://imgur.com/NhjeCxB)

The formula reflects my spreadsheet in that my data is in row A2-A4799 and B2-B4799 and in that my tab is called "export". Everything else is copied directly from what I found